# python flask framework: how to execute this method that make a html file

Tags: python, html, database, flask

I'm new in python and I'm learning flask framework from this tutorial:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views
this is the code I have:

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask,request,session,g,redirect,url_for,abort,render_template,flash
from contextlib import closing

DATABASE= './flaskr.db'
DEBUG= True
SECRET_KEY = '123456789'
USERNAME= 'admin'
PASSWORD='default'

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = connect_db()

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

print(dir(app.route))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """I want to execute show_entries() here"""
```

And I want to execute show_entries() method to make the html file as the tutorial said but I dont know how.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using an ORM like peewee or sqlalchemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all add this code to last part of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """I want to execute show_entries() here"""
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then run your application from shell

```
python flaskr.py
```

Then go to your browser and open http://localhost:5000/

When you open this route ("/") the related view function for this route (show_entries) will be invoked.

You can have an other route and view function for example

```
@app.route('/myname')
def show_my_name():
    return "My name is Cold_Fire"
```

and you can run this view function by going to http://localhost:5000/myname

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what Flask is doing. When you go in your browser to `http://localhost:5000/`, the method `show_entries` will be executed and respond with the HTML content generated by `render_template`. You might want to re-read the Flask [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

Try like below snippet.

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    """I want to execute show_entries() here"""
    import webbrowser
    app.run(debug=True)
    webbrowser.open("http://localhost:5000/") # or just open your browser and go to the url listed here
```

Comment: I did it but after the line app.run() it won't continue to webbrowser.open()

Comment: sure all its doing is opening the webbrowser ... you could probably switch the two lines ...